# View Render output in bootstrap tab style

Tags: views, theming

I have an Unformatted list style view with 2 grouping:

Grouping field Nr.1: Allestimento.
Grouping field Nr.2: Descrizione

(allestimento and descrizione fields are excluded from display.)

Now I want alter the output of the tpl files to render the 2 groupin like bootstrap tabs (group n1) and nested pils (group n2).
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

But i have no idea how can i do this... I made this by jquery but something the page not render this so I prefare do it by php...
I hope you can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's better to create two seperate view (display blocks). One shoud be grouped by Allestimento and other one by Descrizione. Create for the page custom template and add tabs there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the views templating system to create markup exactly how bootstrap wants it then include the javascript - you can work out which templates to override by clicking the theme information link in the view.

In practice it's the sort of thing that is a hell of a lot easier if you do a [Entity field query](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708) and return a block with the correct markup from a small custom module because you'll have to fiddle about with 2 or 3 views templates to get the right output, but it should be possible with views.